# HttpResponseRedirect question

Tags: python, django, django-views

Cant we send a dictionary variable when using HttpResponseRedirect

```
        render_to_response('edited/display.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request,{'newlist': newlist}))

    //How can the dictionary and the request sent back again

    //sumthing like this

    return HttpResponseRedirect('edited/display.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request,{'newlist': newlist}))
```

Answer (score 4):

Response redirect as name suggests, redirects the user's browser to new URL, so it doesn't make any sense to pass anything else except the new location in HttpResponseRedirect

If you want to pass some data, so that in the `view` of new location url you can check for that data, pass it as url arguments e.g.

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('edited/display.html?msg=I was redirected')
```

Answer (score 2):

So let me add another answer additional to existing ones:

```
my_url = reverse("my_app.views.my_path") + "?action_result=124"
return HttpResponseRedirect(my_url)
```

reverse function is: `from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse`

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect):

> The constructor takes a single argument -- the path to redirect to. This can be a fully qualified URL (e.g. 'http://www.yahoo.com/search/') or an absolute URL with no domain (e.g. '/search/').

Answer (score 0):

What you are really looking for, I think is the `redirect` function introduced in 1.1

You can instead use, for your case,

```
redirect(view_name,view_parameter)
```

For that, it may be necessary to modify your view first, to take the new_list parameter, or pass to it, the slug or the id, it takes.